# How to get number of days of all month

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating whole year calender, How to get numbers of days of month in Flutter?
e.g., January ->  31, Fabruary -> 28/29(as per year), March -> 31 So on...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use package https://pub.dev/packages/date_util 
With dateUtility.daysInMonth

code snippet

```
var dateUtility = DateUtil();
var day1 = dateUtility.daysInMonth(2, 2019);
print(day1);
var day2 = dateUtility.daysInMonth(2, 2018);
print(day2);
```

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:date_util/date_util.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the home page of your application. It is stateful, meaning
  // that it has a State object (defined below) that contains fields that affect
  // how it looks.

  // This class is the configuration for the state. It holds the values (in this
  // case the title) provided by the parent (in this case the App widget) and
  // used by the build method of the State. Fields in a Widget subclass are
  // always marked "final".

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    var dateUtility = DateUtil();
    var day1 = dateUtility.daysInMonth(2, 2019);
    print(day1);
    var day2 = dateUtility.daysInMonth(2, 2018);
    print(day2);

    setState(() {
      // This call to setState tells the Flutter framework that something has
      // changed in this State, which causes it to rerun the build method below
      // so that the display can reflect the updated values. If we changed
      // _counter without calling setState(), then the build method would not be
      // called again, and so nothing would appear to happen.
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // This method is rerun every time setState is called, for instance as done
    // by the _incrementCounter method above.
    //
    // The Flutter framework has been optimized to make rerunning build methods
    // fast, so that you can just rebuild anything that needs updating rather
    // than having to individually change instances of widgets.
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        // Here we take the value from the MyHomePage object that was created by
        // the App.build method, and use it to set our appbar title.
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        // Center is a layout widget. It takes a single child and positions it
        // in the middle of the parent.
        child: Column(
          // Column is also a layout widget. It takes a list of children and
          // arranges them vertically. By default, it sizes itself to fit its
          // children horizontally, and tries to be as tall as its parent.
          //
          // Invoke "debug painting" (press "p" in the console, choose the
          // "Toggle Debug Paint" action from the Flutter Inspector in Android
          // Studio, or the "Toggle Debug Paint" command in Visual Studio Code)
          // to see the wireframe for each widget.
          //
          // Column has various properties to control how it sizes itself and
          // how it positions its children. Here we use mainAxisAlignment to
          // center the children vertically; the main axis here is the vertical
          // axis because Columns are vertical (the cross axis would be
          // horizontal).
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

Output

```
I/flutter (11462): 28
I/flutter (11462): 28
```

Comment: This package doesn't support null safety

Answer (score 28):

Using `date1.difference(date2).inDays` **is NOT correct**. For some dates it will return incorrect results, like for `DateTime(2020, 3)`. 
This is because the Duration is based on seconds calculations. And inDays implementation is build with assumption that days are always have the same number of seconds (`_duration ~/ Duration.microsecondsPerDay`) which is not true.

But instead of this you can just use:

```
DateTime(date.year, date.month + 1, 0).day
```

Comment: And what will happen in 12 months according to your calculations with + 1? 13 month?

Comment: date.month starts by 0 (for January) and ends by 12 (for december) so it is no problem.

Answer (score 13):

You can simply use the [quiver.time](https://pub.dev/packages/quiver#quivertime) library:

```
import 'package:quiver/time.dart';

daysInMonth(year, month);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can simply count duration in days without any third-party libs.

```
int daysInMonth = DateTimeRange(
                       start: date,
                       end: DateTime(date.year, date.month + 1))
                    .duration
                    .inDays;
```

Answer (score 10):

Without using any packages you could use this:

```
DateTime x1 = DateTime(2019,1,0).toUtc();
var y1 = DateTime(2019,2,0).toUtc().difference(x1).inDays;
```

Comment: this should be the right answer, you could also just use: ```DateTime(year, month+1, 0).day``` where month is the month that you want to know the number of days it has

Comment: @JoseJet I prefer your way.

Answer (score 8):

This should do it.

```
void main() {
  var now = DateTime.now();
  print(daysInMonth(now));
}

int daysInMonth(DateTime date){
  var firstDayThisMonth = new DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day);
  var firstDayNextMonth = new DateTime(firstDayThisMonth.year, firstDayThisMonth.month + 1, firstDayThisMonth.day);
  return firstDayNextMonth.difference(firstDayThisMonth).inDays;
}
```

prints:

```
30
```

Comment: You should also consider year change, not just month.

Comment: This implementation would not work when the current month is December. This would give number of days to be 180+

Answer (score 7):

**Simple Way**

```
 int daysInMonth(DateTime date) =>  DateTimeRange(
  start:  DateTime(date.year, date.month,1),
  end: DateTime(date.year, date.month + 1))
  .duration
  .inDays;

print("Days in current month is ${daysInMonth(DateTime.now())}");
```

Answer (score 6):

No packages needed.

```
final daysInMonth = DateUtils.getDaysInMonth(year, month);
```

[reference](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DateUtils/getDaysInMonth.html)

Answer (score 3):

```
extension DaysInMonthExtension on DateTime {
int get daysInMonth {
return DateTime(this.year, this.month + 1, 1)
    .difference(DateTime(this.year, this.month, 1))
    .inDays;
}
}

var x = DateTime(2022, 03).daysInMonth;
print(x); // 31
```

Comment: This answer was reviewed in the [Low Quality Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/help/review-low-quality). Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Code only answers are **not considered good answers**, and are likely to be downvoted and/or deleted because they are **less useful** to a community of learners. It's only obvious to you. Explain what it does, and how it's different / **better** than existing 9 answers. [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32612163)

Answer (score 1):

```
int year = DateTime.now().year;

int month = DateTime.now().month;

DateTime thisMonth = DateTime(year,month,0);

DateTime nextMonth = DateTime(year,month+1,0);

int days =  nextMonth.difference(thisMonth).inDays;

print("Days In This Month: $days");
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Karim's Answer

The more better approach would be this way we will also account for year change.

```
  var firstDayThisMonth = new DateTime(date.year, 12, date.day);
  int nextMonth = firstDayThisMonth.month + 1 < 13 ? firstDayThisMonth.month + 1 : (firstDayThisMonth.month + 1) % 12;
  int nextYear = firstDayThisMonth.month + 1 < 13 ? firstDayThisMonth.year :  firstDayThisMonth.year + 1;
  var firstDayNextMonth = new DateTime(nextYear, nextMonth, firstDayThisMonth.day);
  print(firstDayNextMonth.difference(firstDayThisMonth).inDays);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest way to get the days in the month:

```dart
final daysInMonth = DateTime(currentDate.year, currentDate.month + 1, 0).day;
debugPrint(daysInMonth.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use any packages you can simply use the following code:

```
// Use the date you want to, in my case I want today
DateTime _selectedCalendarDate = DateTime.now();

// use the currently selected date's year and month as the start date
DateTime startDate = DateTime(_selectedCalendarDate.year, _selectedCalendarDate.month);

// use the next month depending on start date
DateTime endDate = DateTime(_selectedCalendarDate.year, _selectedCalendarDate.month + 1);

int daysInMonth = DateTimeRange(start: startDate, end: endDate).duration.inDays;
print(daysInMonth);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply by getting the difference between two months in days,
This will return the days of the current month whether it is 31, 30, or 28 days

```
DateTime(selecteddate.year, selecteddate.month+1, 1).difference(DateTime(selecteddate.year, selecteddate.month, 1)).inDays
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. **It would be really useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?