# Using an algorithm to generate days in a month

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm pretty new to Flutter and programming in general and I'm working on this mini project but I'm stuck.

I've created a list of the months in the year and I want to generate the days in the corresponding month when a user taps on a month.

The idea I have for generating the days is quite simple. When I created the list of months, I did so using a class and constructor. This constructor will ask for the month and the number of the month. January has the number "1", February has "2" through to December which has "12"

So I plan on creating a for loop which will count from one to thirty-one (days in a month). It will count to 28,30 or 31 based on the number associated with the month. So if the user taps on January, it has to count to 31 days and generate a list of days, if its February then 28.

As you will see from my code, I've already gotten the month part down but generating the days is a problem.

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(home: home(), title: 'Flutter Demo', theme: ThemeData());
  }
}

class home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _homeState createState() => _homeState();
}

class _homeState extends State<home> {
  List<months> monthoftheyear = [
    months(month: "January", id: 1),
    months(month: "February", id: 2),
    months(month: "March", id: 3),
    months(month: "April", id: 4),
    months(month: "May", id: 5),
    months(month: "June", id: 6),
    months(month: "July", id: 7),
    months(month: "August", id: 8),
    months(month: "September", id: 9),
    months(month: "October", id: 10),
    months(month: "November", id: 11),
    months(month: "December", id: 12),
  ];

  Widget monthtemp(display) {
    return FlatButton(
      child: Card(
        child: Text(display.month),
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
            children:
                monthoftheyear.map((display) => monthtemp(display)).toList()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

for (int i = 0; i>= 31; i++);

if (the month id is 1 then the for loop should count up to 31 and put it in cards,
if its feb, then it should count up to 28 etc)

Comment: Could you fix the indents of your code?

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58762347/how-to-get-number-of-days-of-all-month-in-dart-flutter) about days by month could be of help to you.

Comment: Not 29 days? Do you live somewhere without leap days?

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use the search function: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37798397/dart-create-a-list-from-0-to-n) already provides a number of partial solutions. I think something like this should work:

```
// look up number of days for this month in a small lookup table
var nrOfDays = ...;

// generate a list with all days
var days = Iterable<int>.generate(nrOfDays + 1).skip(1).toList();

// do something with your days to display them
var displayedDays = days.map((day) => ...);
```